# HttpClient with WebView

Tags: android, webview, httpclient

I am using an httpclient to display a web page in the webView using loadDataWithBaseURL. My web site has some links and I want to continue using httpClient when user clicks on the link. Is it possible to do?
In this case when user clicks on the link i must intercept the link, so that my browser will load it, then stop loading it and use HttpGet. Does it sound reasonable enough?

**EDIT:**
Yup, that was a good idea..
firstly you set a client

```
comments.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

                String LinkTag = "";
                try {
                    LinkTag = client.httpGet(url);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                comments.loadDataWithBaseURL("BaseWebUrl", LinkTag, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And secondly you must create an httpClient to handle your Posts and Gets and maybe other methods as well

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is after you call `HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();` is set it as a public static variable in the first activity or class that you are using it in. Then when the user clicks on a link and you have to call HttpGet you will just set the `new HttpClient newName = originalClass.hc;` and this will store your cookies.

```
public class FirstClass{  
   public static HttpClient hc = new DefaultClient();
   {make the original get call}

public class NewClass{
    //new httpclient
    {HttpClient newHC = FirstClass.hc;}
```