# android http request to full site (avoid mobile version)

Tags: android, http

I know how to make http request on android.
But how can i make an http request to a website and gurarantee the response is from the full site not the **mobile version** ?

Thanks

Comment: modify the user agent strings being sent?

Comment: you can get some info from my similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13555108/1548085, there is still no concrete answer, but it may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the user agent String ( to make it appear coming from a desktop browser ) Refer to link below :

[Setting user agent of a java URLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the request headers or change all by which one can determine that it is a mobile device
hope it help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Your user agent like that.

```
 String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101          
 Firefox/4.0";

    mWebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";

        try {
            httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            // Add your data

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```